# Re-start dependent OSGI bundles on dependency bundle re-start?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have OSGI bundles implementing API specified in another bundle (addded as dependency).
Is there any way to specify that whenever API bundle is restarted, restart the implenting bundles (dependents)?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. Perhaps if you could explain why you think you need to, then an alternative solution can be offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call refresh and all bundles will be restarted that had package wirings to the old API bundle. You can call refresh on the console or programmatically FrameworkWiring.refreshBundles(...) For more information you can check the [javadoc](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html#refreshBundles%28java.util.Collection,%20org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener...%29) of the mentioned function.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you use Declarative Services or Blueprint in the implementation bundles to expose the services declared in the API bundle you can get such behavior.

In release 5 there is the Subsystem Specification where you can have more than one bundle inside a composite that will share a single life-cycle [1].

[1] - http://coderthoughts.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/osgi-subsystems.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i guess the OSGi container does this internally whenever the dependant bundle 
changes. There is no need for extra configuration.

However, if this is not the case, you can give a try by using 
the manifest header "Require-Bundle" rather than "import-package" to show 
the dependency to other bundles.